# Why can't I setState the data I've successfully in React?

Tags: reactjs, rest

So I'm new to React, and having trouble fetching API. I've successfully fetched data object(I've checked it with `console.log()`, but somehow cannot setState it. Please see the code below. It's my full code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import EachCake from './EachCake';

class Cake extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._fetchApiEachCake();
    }

    _renderEachCake = () => {
        return <EachCake 
        image={this.cake_object.image}
        source={this.cake_object.source}
        body={this.cake_object.body}
        />
    }
    
    _fetchApiEachCake = () => {
        return fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cake/3")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .then(data => this.setState({cake_object : data}))
        // .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.cake_object ? this._renderEachCake() : "Loading this cake"}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Cake
```

For some reason, all I get on the screen is "Loading this cake". What do you think is the problem?

Comment: You're not returning anything from the second `.then`, so the data is undefined in `setState`. If you remove the entire line `.then(data => console.log(data))` it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import EachCake from './EachCake';

class Cake extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        //  state initialization is optional also, useful for default values
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._fetchApiEachCake();
    }

    _renderEachCake = () => {
        return (
          <EachCake 
            image={this.state.cake_object.image} // 
            source={this.state.cake_object.source}
            body={this.state.cake_object.body}
          />
      )
   }
    
    _fetchApiEachCake = () => {
        //  you can also remove return here
        return fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cake/3")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data) || data) // 
        .then(data => this.setState({cake_object : data}))
        // .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.cake_object ? this._renderEachCake() : "Loading this cake"}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Cake
```

must be grabbed from the state not directly from this reference.
 console.log doesn't return anything, so you must return data yourself oق combine setState and logging step both in one step e.g.

```js
.then(cake_object => console.log(cake_object) || this.setState({ cake_object }))
```

> The [then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method returns a Promise.

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer most of all. I've tried as you told, but then I get ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined.```.

Comment: thank you, what does your logged data show? It could be for fetch problem, and you should provide fall back and check data existence.

Comment: I do get the correct data in my console. So it means it fetches properly. I just can't put it(?) into my state.

Comment: could you change functions to non-es6 and bind them in the constructor

Comment: No that was not a problem, I copied the above code and fetch it from JSONPlaceholder and it worked. [codesand-box](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-antonelli-ly2b3?file=/src/Cake.tsx)

Comment: Oh... then what do you think is the problem? I don't have to map when rendering, when the data I'm fetching is a single object, right?

Comment: I guess your answer is no, just pass the object to set State as the one you want to retrieve later

Comment: I've copied+pasted your code in codesandbox and just changed the url, and it worked!! I don't understand what I've done wrong but well now it works...

Comment: it may be a typo or it is not your debugging time :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to check if the data is loaded or not you should use the callback `this.setstate({key: value}, () => {//do something})`
you can use this to set a flag whether data has been loaded into state or not. and i also think that you should initialize that cake_object to null.
so after that your code would be like:

```
this.state = {
       loaded: false,
       cake_object: null
    }



  _fetchApiEachCake = () => {
    return fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cake/3")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .then(data => this.setState({cake_object : data}, () => {
            console.log(this.state.cake_object);
            this.setState({loaded: true});
     }))
    // .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.loaded ? this._renderEachCake() : "Loading this cake"}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer most of all. I've tried as you told, but then I get ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined.```.

Answer (score 1):

2 changes :
1.

```
this.state = {
   cake_object:null,
}
```

2. 

```
 _fetchApiEachCake = () => {
        return fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cake/3")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
              console.log(data) 
              this.setState({cake_object : data})
         })
        // .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }
```

Hopefully it works!

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer most of all. I've tried as you told, but then I get ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined.```.

Comment: Hi, Ryan Oh, I believe you are having this error because of the way you are accessing it, instead of using image={this.cake_object.image} try to access it using image={this.state.cake_object.image}.

Comment: Yes you're right. It took me hours to figure it out. Can't believe I made such mistake.  :(

Comment: Hahah.. hopefully it started working. Happy coding :) !